# Rename in DOS cause Syntax Error on Extensionless File

Tags: dos, rename

When I use

`ren "C:\folder\file" "C:\folder\file.txt"`

Got error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

but if I `CD` to the folder and use

`ren "file" "file.txt"`

No error and works.

My question is, how to rename an extensionless file with path

Comment: Is this _really_ DOS (such as MSDOS 6.22) or is the cmd.exe command interpreter in Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
ren C:\folder\file file.txt
```

you only need the path once

What you also could have done is

```
move C:\folder\file C:\folder\file.txt
```

With move, you can specify the path for both

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me :

```
rename "D:\DATA\previousfilename" newfilename
```

eg :->

```
rename "D:\DATA\abcd.jpg" mnop.jpg
```